# sort list by number of characters in title

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

This is an exercise from the book "Learn jQuery 3".
I need to change the code so when i click on the title title the books are sorted by number of characters in the title not alphabetically like it is right now.

the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chapter 12</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <h1>Chapter 12</h1>

      <table id="t-1" class="sortable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th class="sort-alpha">Title</th>
            <th class="sort-alpha">Author(s)</th>
            <th class="sort-date">Publish Date</th>
            <th class="sort-numeric">Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="images/2862_OS.jpg" alt="Drupal 7"></td>
            <td>Drupal 7</td>
            <td>David <span class="sort-key">Mercer</span></td>
            <td>September 2010</td>
            <td>$44.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/3685EN_Amazon%20SimpleDB_LITE_0.jpg" alt="Amazon SimpleDB: LITE">
            </td>
            <td>Amazon SimpleDB: LITE</td>
            <td>Prabhakar <span class="sort-key">Chaganti</span>, Rich Helms</td>
            <td>May 2011</td>
            <td>$9.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="images/1847194141.jpg" alt="Object-Oriented JavaScript"></td>
            <td>Object-Oriented JavaScript</td>
            <td>Stoyan <span class="sort-key">Stefanov</span></td>
            <td>July 2008</td>
            <td>$39.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/0042_MockupCover_0.jpg" alt="jQuery 1.4 Reference Guide">
            </td>
            <td>
              jQuery 1.4 Reference Guide
            </td>
            <td>
              Karl <span class="sort-key">Swedberg</span>, Jonathan Chaffer
            </td>
            <td>
              January 2010

            </td>
            <td>
              $39.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/0386OT_Cocoa%20and%20OBjective-C%20Cookbookcov.jpg" alt="Cocoa and Objective-C Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>
              Cocoa and Objective-C Cookbook
            </td>
            <td>
              Jeff <span class="sort-key">Hawkins</span>
            </td>

            <td>
              May 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $39.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/4668_Python%20Testing%20Cookbook.jpg" alt="Python Testing Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>
              Python Testing Cookbook
            </td>
            <td>
              Greg L. <span class="sort-key">Turnquist</span>

            </td>
            <td>
              May 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $44.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/3760OS_Linux%20Shell%20Scripting%20Cookbook.jpg" alt="Linux Shell Scripting Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>
              Linux Shell Scripting Cookbook
            </td>
            <td>
              Sarath <span class="sort-key">Lakshman</span>

            </td>
            <td>
              January 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $44.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/4965OS_Nginx%201%20Web%20Server%20Implementation%20Cookbook.jpg" alt="Nginx 1 Web Server Implementation Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>
              Nginx 1 Web Server Implementation Cookbook
            </td>
            <td>
              Dipankar <span class="sort-key">Sarkar</span>

            </td>
            <td>
              May 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $39.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/1048OT_HTML5%20Multimedia%20Development%20Cookbookcov.jpg" alt="HTML5 Multimedia Development Cookbookcov.jpg">
            </td>
            <td>
              HTML5 Multimedia Development Cookbookcov.jpg
            </td>
            <td>
              Dale <span class="sort-key">Cruse</span>, Lee Jordan

            </td>
            <td>
              May 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $39.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/0942OT_Core%20Data%20Essentials_0.jpg" alt="Core Data Essentials.jpg">
            </td>
            <td>
              Core Data Essentials.jpg
            </td>
            <td>
              B.M. <span class="sort-key">Harwani</span>

            </td>
            <td>
              April 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $44.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/3524OS_WordPress%203%20Plugin%20Development%20Essentials_0.jpg" alt="WordPress 3 Plugin Development Essentials">
            </td>
            <td>
              WordPress 3 Plugin Development Essentials
            </td>
            <td>
              Brian <span class="sort-key">Bondari</span>, Everett Griffiths

            </td>
            <td>
              March 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $39.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/9867_Latex%20cov.jpg" alt="LaTeX Beginner's Guide">
            </td>
            <td>
              LaTeX Beginner's Guide
            </td>
            <td>
              Stefan <span class="sort-key">Kottwitz</span>

            </td>
            <td>
              March 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $44.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/2923OS_Panda3D%20game%20developer%E2%80%99s%20cookbook.jpg" alt="Panda3D 1.7 Game Developer's Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>
              Panda3D 1.7 Game Developer's Cookbook
            </td>
            <td>
              Christoph <span class="sort-key">Lang</span>

            </td>
            <td>
              March 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $44.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/1926_Cake%20PHP%201.3cov.jpg" alt="CakePHP 1.3 Application Development Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>
              CakePHP 1.3 Application Development Cookbook
            </td>
            <td>
              Mariano <span class="sort-key">Iglesias</span>

            </td>
            <td>
              March 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $39.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/4804os_mockupcover_ex.jpg" alt="Magento 1.4 Themes Design">
            </td>
            <td>
              Magento 1.4 Themes Design
            </td>
            <td>
              Richard <span class="sort-key">Carter</span>

            </td>
            <td>
              January 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $39.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/0349OS_MockupCover_0.jpg" alt="Django JavaScript Integration: AJAX and jQuery">
            </td>
            <td>
              Django JavaScript Integration: AJAX and jQuery
            </td>
            <td>
              Jonathan <span class="sort-key">Hayward</span>

            </td>
            <td>
              January 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $44.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/1445OS_MockupCover_Magento_1.4_Development_Cookbook_cb.jpg" alt="Magento 1.4 Development Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>
              Magento 1.4 Development Cookbook
            </td>
            <td>
              Nurul <span class="sort-key">Ferdous</span>

            </td>
            <td>
              December 2010
            </td>
            <td>
              $44.99
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <table id="t-2" class="sortable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th data-sort='{"key":"title"}'>Title</th>
            <th data-sort='{"key":"authors"}'>Author(s)</th>
            <th data-sort='{"key":"publishedYM"}'>Publish Date</th>
            <th data-sort='{"key":"price"}'>Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"2862_OS.jpg","title":"DRUPAL 7","authors":"MERCER DAVID","published":"September 2010","price":44.99,"publishedYM":"2010-09"}'>
            <td><img src="images/2862_OS.jpg" alt="Drupal 7">
            </td>
            <td>Drupal 7</td>
            <td>David Mercer</td>
            <td>September 2010</td>
            <td>$44.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"3685EN_Amazon%20SimpleDB_LITE_0.jpg","title":"AMAZON SIMPLEDB: LITE","authors":"CHAGANTI PRABHAKAR HELMS RICH","published":"May 2011","price":9.99,"publishedYM":"2011-05"}'>
            <td><img src="images/3685EN_Amazon%20SimpleDB_LITE_0.jpg" alt="Amazon SimpleDB: LITE">
            </td>
            <td>Amazon SimpleDB: LITE</td>
            <td>Prabhakar Chaganti, Rich Helms</td>

            <td>May 2011</td>
            <td>$9.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"1847194141.jpg","title":"OBJECT-ORIENTED JAVASCRIPT","authors":"STEFANOV STOYAN","published":"July 2008","price":39.99,"publishedYM":"2008-07"}'>
            <td><img src="images/1847194141.jpg" alt="Object-Oriented JavaScript">
            </td>
            <td>Object-Oriented JavaScript</td>
            <td>Stoyan Stefanov</td>
            <td>July 2008</td>
            <td>$39.99</td>
          </tr>

          <tr data-book='{"img":"0042_MockupCover_0.jpg","title":"JQUERY 1.4 REFERENCE GUIDE","authors":"SWEDBERG KARL CHAFFER JONATHAN","published":"January 2010","price":39.99,"publishedYM":"2010-01"}'>
            <td><img src="images/0042_MockupCover_0.jpg" alt="jQuery 1.4 Reference Guide">
            </td>
            <td>jQuery 1.4 Reference Guide</td>
            <td>Karl Swedberg, Jonathan Chaffer</td>
            <td>January 2010</td>
            <td>$39.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"0386OT_Cocoa%20and%20OBjective-C%20Cookbookcov.jpg","title":"COCOA AND OBJECTIVE-C COOKBOOK","authors":"HAWKINS JEFF","published":"May 2011","price":39.99,"publishedYM":"2011-05"}'>
            <td><img src="images/0386OT_Cocoa%20and%20OBjective-C%20Cookbookcov.jpg" alt="Cocoa and Objective-C Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>Cocoa and Objective-C Cookbook</td>

            <td>Jeff Hawkins</td>
            <td>May 2011</td>
            <td>$39.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"4668_Python%20Testing%20Cookbook.jpg","title":"PYTHON TESTING COOKBOOK","authors":"TURNQUIST GREG L.","published":"May 2011","price":44.99,"publishedYM":"2011-05"}'>
            <td><img src="images/4668_Python%20Testing%20Cookbook.jpg" alt="Python Testing Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>Python Testing Cookbook</td>
            <td>Greg L. Turnquist</td>
            <td>May 2011</td>
            <td>$44.99</td>

          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"3760OS_Linux%20Shell%20Scripting%20Cookbook.jpg","title":"LINUX SHELL SCRIPTING COOKBOOK","authors":"LAKSHMAN SARATH","published":"January 2011","price":44.99,"publishedYM":"2011-01"}'>
            <td><img src="images/3760OS_Linux%20Shell%20Scripting%20Cookbook.jpg" alt="Linux Shell Scripting Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>Linux Shell Scripting Cookbook</td>
            <td>Sarath Lakshman</td>
            <td>January 2011</td>
            <td>$44.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"4965OS_Nginx%201%20Web%20Server%20Implementation%20Cookbook.jpg","title":"NGINX 1 WEB SERVER IMPLEMENTATION COOKBOOK","authors":"SARKAR DIPANKAR","published":"May 2011","price":39.99,"publishedYM":"2011-05"}'>
            <td><img src="images/4965OS_Nginx%201%20Web%20Server%20Implementation%20Cookbook.jpg" alt="Nginx 1 Web Server Implementation Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>Nginx 1 Web Server Implementation Cookbook</td>

            <td>Dipankar Sarkar</td>
            <td>May 2011</td>
            <td>$39.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"1048OT_HTML5%20Multimedia%20Development%20Cookbookcov.jpg","title":"HTML5 MULTIMEDIA DEVELOPMENT COOKBOOKCOV.JPG","authors":"CRUSE DALE JORDAN LEE","published":"May 2011","price":39.99,"publishedYM":"2011-05"}'>
            <td><img src="images/1048OT_HTML5%20Multimedia%20Development%20Cookbookcov.jpg" alt="HTML5 Multimedia Development Cookbookcov.jpg">
            </td>
            <td>HTML5 Multimedia Development Cookbookcov.jpg</td>
            <td>Dale Cruse, Lee Jordan</td>
            <td>May 2011</td>
            <td>$39.99</td>

          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"0942OT_Core%20Data%20Essentials_0.jpg","title":"CORE DATA ESSENTIALS.JPG","authors":"HARWANI B.M.","published":"April 2011","price":44.99,"publishedYM":"2011-04"}'>
            <td><img src="images/0942OT_Core%20Data%20Essentials_0.jpg" alt="Core Data Essentials.jpg">
            </td>
            <td>Core Data Essentials.jpg</td>
            <td>B.M. Harwani</td>
            <td>April 2011</td>
            <td>$44.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"3524OS_WordPress%203%20Plugin%20Development%20Essentials_0.jpg","title":"WORDPRESS 3 PLUGIN DEVELOPMENT ESSENTIALS","authors":"BONDARI BRIAN GRIFFITHS EVERETT","published":"March 2011","price":39.99,"publishedYM":"2011-03"}'>
            <td><img src="images/3524OS_WordPress%203%20Plugin%20Development%20Essentials_0.jpg" alt="WordPress 3 Plugin Development Essentials">
            </td>
            <td>WordPress 3 Plugin Development Essentials</td>

            <td>Brian Bondari, Everett Griffiths</td>
            <td>March 2011</td>
            <td>$39.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"9867_Latex%20cov.jpg","title":"LATEX BEGINNER&rsquo;S GUIDE","authors":"KOTTWITZ STEFAN","published":"March 2011","price":44.99,"publishedYM":"2011-03"}'>
            <td><img src="images/9867_Latex%20cov.jpg" alt="LaTeX Beginner's Guide">
            </td>
            <td>LaTeX Beginner's Guide</td>
            <td>Stefan Kottwitz</td>
            <td>March 2011</td>
            <td>$44.99</td>

          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"2923OS_Panda3D%20game%20developer%E2%80%99s%20cookbook.jpg","title":"PANDA3D 1.7 GAME DEVELOPER&rsquo;S COOKBOOK","authors":"LANG CHRISTOPH","published":"March 2011","price":44.99,"publishedYM":"2011-03"}'>
            <td><img src="images/2923OS_Panda3D%20game%20developer%E2%80%99s%20cookbook.jpg" alt="Panda3D 1.7 Game Developer's Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>Panda3D 1.7 Game Developer's Cookbook</td>
            <td>Christoph Lang</td>
            <td>March 2011</td>
            <td>$44.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"1926_Cake%20PHP%201.3cov.jpg","title":"CAKEPHP 1.3 APPLICATION DEVELOPMENT COOKBOOK","authors":"IGLESIAS MARIANO","published":"March 2011","price":39.99,"publishedYM":"2011-03"}'>
            <td><img src="images/1926_Cake%20PHP%201.3cov.jpg" alt="CakePHP 1.3 Application Development Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>CakePHP 1.3 Application Development Cookbook</td>

            <td>Mariano Iglesias</td>
            <td>March 2011</td>
            <td>$39.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"4804os_mockupcover_ex.jpg","title":"MAGENTO 1.4 THEMES DESIGN","authors":"CARTER RICHARD","published":"January 2011","price":39.99,"publishedYM":"2011-01"}'>
            <td><img src="images/4804os_mockupcover_ex.jpg" alt="Magento 1.4 Themes Design">
            </td>
            <td>Magento 1.4 Themes Design</td>
            <td>Richard Carter</td>
            <td>January 2011</td>
            <td>$39.99</td>

          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"0349OS_MockupCover_0.jpg","title":"DJANGO JAVASCRIPT INTEGRATION: AJAX AND JQUERY","authors":"HAYWARD JONATHAN","published":"January 2011","price":44.99,"publishedYM":"2011-01"}'>
            <td><img src="images/0349OS_MockupCover_0.jpg" alt="Django JavaScript Integration: AJAX and jQuery">
            </td>
            <td>Django JavaScript Integration: AJAX and jQuery</td>
            <td>Jonathan Hayward</td>
            <td>January 2011</td>
            <td>$44.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"1445OS_MockupCover_Magento_1.4_Development_Cookbook_cb.jpg","title":"MAGENTO 1.4 DEVELOPMENT COOKBOOK","authors":"FERDOUS NURUL","published":"December 2010","price":44.99,"publishedYM":"2010-12"}'>
            <td><img src="images/1445OS_MockupCover_Magento_1.4_Development_Cookbook_cb.jpg" alt="Magento 1.4 Development Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>Magento 1.4 Development Cookbook</td>

            <td>Nurul Ferdous</td>
            <td>December 2010</td>
            <td>$44.99</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <table id="t-3" class="sortable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th data-sort='{"key":"title"}'>Title</th>
            <th data-sort='{"key":"authors"}'>Author(s)</th>
            <th data-sort='{"key":"publishedYM"}'>Publish Date</th>
            <th data-sort='{"key":"price"}'>Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        </tbody>

      </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and is short the script:

```
<script>

     
         /************************************************
  Set up table headings.
************************************************/
(($) => {
  $.cssHooks.glowColor = {
    set(elem, value) {
      elem.style.textShadow = value == 'none' ?
        '' : `0 0 2px ${value}`;
    }
  };
})(jQuery);

$(() => {
  $('table')
    .each((i, table) => {
      $('<h3/>', {
        'class': 'table-title',
        id: `table-title-${i}`,
        text: `Table ${i + 1}`,
        data: { index: i },
        click(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(table).fadeToggle();
        },
        css: { glowColor: '#00ff00', cursor: 'pointer' }
      }).insertBefore(table);
    });
});

/************************************************
  Table 1: Sorting by parsing cell contents.
************************************************/
$(() => {
  const comparator = (a, b, direction = 1) =>
    a < b ?
      -direction :
      (a > b ? direction : 0);
  const sortKeys = {
    date: $cell => Date.parse(`1 ${$cell.text()}`),
    alpha: $cell => $.trim(
      $cell.find('span.sort-key').text() + ' ' +
      $cell.text().toUpperCase()
    ),
    numeric($cell) {
      const key = parseFloat(
        $cell
          .text()
          .replace(/^[^\d.]*/, '')
      );
      return isNaN(key) ? 0 : key;
    }
  };

  $('#t-1')
    .find('thead th')
    .slice(1)
    .each((i, element) => {
      $(element).data(
        'keyType',
        element.className.replace(/^sort-/,'')
      );
    })
    .wrapInner($('<a/>').attr('href', '#'))
    .addClass('sort')
    .on('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      const $target = $(e.currentTarget);
      const column = $target.index();
      const keyType = $target.data('keyType');
      const sortDirection = $target.hasClass('sorted-asc') ?
        -1 : 1;

      $('#t-1')
        .find('tbody > tr')
        .each((i, element) => {
          $(element).data(
            'sortKey',
            sortKeys[keyType](
              $(element)
                .children('td')
                .eq(column)
            )
          );
        })
        .get()
        .sort((a, b) => comparator(
          $(a).data('sortKey'),
          $(b).data('sortKey'),
          sortDirection
        ))
        .forEach((element) => {
          $(element)
            .parent()
            .append(element);
        });

      $target
        .siblings()
        .addBack()
        .removeClass('sorted-asc sorted-desc')
        .end()
        .end()
        .addClass(
          sortDirection == 1 ?
            'sorted-asc' : 'sorted-desc'
        );
    });
});


/************************************************
  Table 2: Sorting by reading HTML5 data.
************************************************/
$(() => {
  const comparator = (a, b, direction = 1) =>
    a < b ?
      -direction :
      (a > b ? direction : 0);

  $('#t-2')
    .find('thead th')
    .slice(1)
    .wrapInner($('<a/>').attr('href', '#'))
    .addClass('sort')
    .on('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      const $target = $(e.currentTarget);
      const column = $target.index();
      const sortKey = $target.data('sort').key;
      const sortDirection = $target.hasClass('sorted-asc') ?
        -1 : 1;

      $('#t-2')
        .find('tbody > tr')
        .get()
        .sort((a, b) => comparator(
          $(a).data('book')[sortKey],
          $(b).data('book')[sortKey],
          sortDirection
        ))
        .forEach((element) => {
          $(element)
            .parent()
            .append(element);
        });

      $target
        .siblings()
        .addBack()
        .removeClass('sorted-asc sorted-desc')
        .end()
        .end()
        .addClass(
          sortDirection == 1 ?
            'sorted-asc' : 'sorted-desc'
        );
    });
});

/************************************************
  Table 3: Sorting by recreating HTML from JSON.
************************************************/
(($) => {
  const buildAuthors = (row, separator = ', ') =>
    row
      .authors
      .map(a => `${a.first_name} ${a.last_name}`)
      .join(separator);

  const buildRow = row =>
    `
      <tr>
        <td><img src="images/${row.img}"></td>
        <td>${row.titleFormatted}</td>
        <td>${row.authorsFormatted}</td>
        <td>${row.published}</td>
        <td>$${row.price}</td>
      </tr>
    `;

  const prepRows = rows =>
    rows
      .map(row => $.extend({}, row, {
        title: row.title.toUpperCase(),
        titleFormatted: row.title,
        authors: buildAuthors(row, ' ').toUpperCase(),
        authorsFormatted: buildAuthors(row)
      }));

  const buildRows = rows =>
    rows
      .map(buildRow)
      .join('');

  Promise.all([$.getJSON('books.json'), $.ready])
    .then(([json]) => {
      $('#t-3')
        .find('tbody')
        .html(buildRows(prepRows(json)));

      const comparator = (a, b, direction = 1) =>
        a < b ?
          -direction :
          (a > b ? direction : 0);

      $('#t-3')
        .find('thead th')
        .slice(1)
        .wrapInner($('<a/>').attr('href', '#'))
        .addClass('sort')
        .on('click', (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();

          const $target = $(e.currentTarget);
          const column = $target.index();
          const sortKey = $target.data('sort').key;
          const sortDirection = $target.hasClass('sorted-asc') ?
            -1 : 1;
          const content = buildRows(
            prepRows(json).sort((a, b) => comparator(
              a[sortKey],
              b[sortKey],
              sortDirection
            ))
          );

          $('#t-3')
            .find('tbody')
            .html(content);

          $target
            .siblings()
            .addBack()
            .removeClass('sorted-asc sorted-desc')
            .end()
            .end()
            .addClass(
              sortDirection == 1 ?
                'sorted-asc' : 'sorted-desc'
            );
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
})(jQuery);

          
          
      </script>
```

I tried to change the data attribute with length but this didnt work.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What code have you changed/made to try this exercise?

Comment: I tried to change the data attribute with length but this didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chapter 12</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <h1>Chapter 12</h1>

      <table id="t-1" class="sortable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th class="sort-alpha">Title</th>
            <th class="sort-alpha">Author(s)</th>
            <th class="sort-date">Publish Date</th>
            <th class="sort-numeric">Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="images/2862_OS.jpg" alt="Drupal 7"></td>
            <td>Drupal 7</td>
            <td>David <span class="sort-key">Mercer</span></td>
            <td>September 2010</td>
            <td>$44.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/3685EN_Amazon%20SimpleDB_LITE_0.jpg" alt="Amazon SimpleDB: LITE">
            </td>
            <td>Amazon SimpleDB: LITE</td>
            <td>Prabhakar <span class="sort-key">Chaganti</span>, Rich Helms</td>
            <td>May 2011</td>
            <td>$9.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="images/1847194141.jpg" alt="Object-Oriented JavaScript"></td>
            <td>Object-Oriented JavaScript</td>
            <td>Stoyan <span class="sort-key">Stefanov</span></td>
            <td>July 2008</td>
            <td>$39.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/0042_MockupCover_0.jpg" alt="jQuery 1.4 Reference Guide">
            </td>
            <td>
              jQuery 1.4 Reference Guide
            </td>
            <td>
              Karl <span class="sort-key">Swedberg</span>, Jonathan Chaffer
            </td>
            <td>
              January 2010

            </td>
            <td>
              $39.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/0386OT_Cocoa%20and%20OBjective-C%20Cookbookcov.jpg" alt="Cocoa and Objective-C Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>
              Cocoa and Objective-C Cookbook
            </td>
            <td>
              Jeff <span class="sort-key">Hawkins</span>
            </td>

            <td>
              May 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $39.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/4668_Python%20Testing%20Cookbook.jpg" alt="Python Testing Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>
              Python Testing Cookbook
            </td>
            <td>
              Greg L. <span class="sort-key">Turnquist</span>

            </td>
            <td>
              May 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $44.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/3760OS_Linux%20Shell%20Scripting%20Cookbook.jpg" alt="Linux Shell Scripting Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>
              Linux Shell Scripting Cookbook
            </td>
            <td>
              Sarath <span class="sort-key">Lakshman</span>

            </td>
            <td>
              January 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $44.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/4965OS_Nginx%201%20Web%20Server%20Implementation%20Cookbook.jpg" alt="Nginx 1 Web Server Implementation Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>
              Nginx 1 Web Server Implementation Cookbook
            </td>
            <td>
              Dipankar <span class="sort-key">Sarkar</span>

            </td>
            <td>
              May 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $39.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/1048OT_HTML5%20Multimedia%20Development%20Cookbookcov.jpg" alt="HTML5 Multimedia Development Cookbookcov.jpg">
            </td>
            <td>
              HTML5 Multimedia Development Cookbookcov.jpg
            </td>
            <td>
              Dale <span class="sort-key">Cruse</span>, Lee Jordan

            </td>
            <td>
              May 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $39.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/0942OT_Core%20Data%20Essentials_0.jpg" alt="Core Data Essentials.jpg">
            </td>
            <td>
              Core Data Essentials.jpg
            </td>
            <td>
              B.M. <span class="sort-key">Harwani</span>

            </td>
            <td>
              April 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $44.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/3524OS_WordPress%203%20Plugin%20Development%20Essentials_0.jpg" alt="WordPress 3 Plugin Development Essentials">
            </td>
            <td>
              WordPress 3 Plugin Development Essentials
            </td>
            <td>
              Brian <span class="sort-key">Bondari</span>, Everett Griffiths

            </td>
            <td>
              March 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $39.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/9867_Latex%20cov.jpg" alt="LaTeX Beginner's Guide">
            </td>
            <td>
              LaTeX Beginner's Guide
            </td>
            <td>
              Stefan <span class="sort-key">Kottwitz</span>

            </td>
            <td>
              March 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $44.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/2923OS_Panda3D%20game%20developer%E2%80%99s%20cookbook.jpg" alt="Panda3D 1.7 Game Developer's Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>
              Panda3D 1.7 Game Developer's Cookbook
            </td>
            <td>
              Christoph <span class="sort-key">Lang</span>

            </td>
            <td>
              March 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $44.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/1926_Cake%20PHP%201.3cov.jpg" alt="CakePHP 1.3 Application Development Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>
              CakePHP 1.3 Application Development Cookbook
            </td>
            <td>
              Mariano <span class="sort-key">Iglesias</span>

            </td>
            <td>
              March 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $39.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/4804os_mockupcover_ex.jpg" alt="Magento 1.4 Themes Design">
            </td>
            <td>
              Magento 1.4 Themes Design
            </td>
            <td>
              Richard <span class="sort-key">Carter</span>

            </td>
            <td>
              January 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $39.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/0349OS_MockupCover_0.jpg" alt="Django JavaScript Integration: AJAX and jQuery">
            </td>
            <td>
              Django JavaScript Integration: AJAX and jQuery
            </td>
            <td>
              Jonathan <span class="sort-key">Hayward</span>

            </td>
            <td>
              January 2011
            </td>
            <td>
              $44.99
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/1445OS_MockupCover_Magento_1.4_Development_Cookbook_cb.jpg" alt="Magento 1.4 Development Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>
              Magento 1.4 Development Cookbook
            </td>
            <td>
              Nurul <span class="sort-key">Ferdous</span>

            </td>
            <td>
              December 2010
            </td>
            <td>
              $44.99
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <table id="t-2" class="sortable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th data-sort='{"key":"title"}'>Title</th>
            <th data-sort='{"key":"authors"}'>Author(s)</th>
            <th data-sort='{"key":"publishedYM"}'>Publish Date</th>
            <th data-sort='{"key":"price"}'>Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"2862_OS.jpg","title":"DRUPAL 7","authors":"MERCER DAVID","published":"September 2010","price":44.99,"publishedYM":"2010-09"}'>
            <td><img src="images/2862_OS.jpg" alt="Drupal 7">
            </td>
            <td>Drupal 7</td>
            <td>David Mercer</td>
            <td>September 2010</td>
            <td>$44.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"3685EN_Amazon%20SimpleDB_LITE_0.jpg","title":"AMAZON SIMPLEDB: LITE","authors":"CHAGANTI PRABHAKAR HELMS RICH","published":"May 2011","price":9.99,"publishedYM":"2011-05"}'>
            <td><img src="images/3685EN_Amazon%20SimpleDB_LITE_0.jpg" alt="Amazon SimpleDB: LITE">
            </td>
            <td>Amazon SimpleDB: LITE</td>
            <td>Prabhakar Chaganti, Rich Helms</td>

            <td>May 2011</td>
            <td>$9.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"1847194141.jpg","title":"OBJECT-ORIENTED JAVASCRIPT","authors":"STEFANOV STOYAN","published":"July 2008","price":39.99,"publishedYM":"2008-07"}'>
            <td><img src="images/1847194141.jpg" alt="Object-Oriented JavaScript">
            </td>
            <td>Object-Oriented JavaScript</td>
            <td>Stoyan Stefanov</td>
            <td>July 2008</td>
            <td>$39.99</td>
          </tr>

          <tr data-book='{"img":"0042_MockupCover_0.jpg","title":"JQUERY 1.4 REFERENCE GUIDE","authors":"SWEDBERG KARL CHAFFER JONATHAN","published":"January 2010","price":39.99,"publishedYM":"2010-01"}'>
            <td><img src="images/0042_MockupCover_0.jpg" alt="jQuery 1.4 Reference Guide">
            </td>
            <td>jQuery 1.4 Reference Guide</td>
            <td>Karl Swedberg, Jonathan Chaffer</td>
            <td>January 2010</td>
            <td>$39.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"0386OT_Cocoa%20and%20OBjective-C%20Cookbookcov.jpg","title":"COCOA AND OBJECTIVE-C COOKBOOK","authors":"HAWKINS JEFF","published":"May 2011","price":39.99,"publishedYM":"2011-05"}'>
            <td><img src="images/0386OT_Cocoa%20and%20OBjective-C%20Cookbookcov.jpg" alt="Cocoa and Objective-C Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>Cocoa and Objective-C Cookbook</td>

            <td>Jeff Hawkins</td>
            <td>May 2011</td>
            <td>$39.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"4668_Python%20Testing%20Cookbook.jpg","title":"PYTHON TESTING COOKBOOK","authors":"TURNQUIST GREG L.","published":"May 2011","price":44.99,"publishedYM":"2011-05"}'>
            <td><img src="images/4668_Python%20Testing%20Cookbook.jpg" alt="Python Testing Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>Python Testing Cookbook</td>
            <td>Greg L. Turnquist</td>
            <td>May 2011</td>
            <td>$44.99</td>

          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"3760OS_Linux%20Shell%20Scripting%20Cookbook.jpg","title":"LINUX SHELL SCRIPTING COOKBOOK","authors":"LAKSHMAN SARATH","published":"January 2011","price":44.99,"publishedYM":"2011-01"}'>
            <td><img src="images/3760OS_Linux%20Shell%20Scripting%20Cookbook.jpg" alt="Linux Shell Scripting Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>Linux Shell Scripting Cookbook</td>
            <td>Sarath Lakshman</td>
            <td>January 2011</td>
            <td>$44.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"4965OS_Nginx%201%20Web%20Server%20Implementation%20Cookbook.jpg","title":"NGINX 1 WEB SERVER IMPLEMENTATION COOKBOOK","authors":"SARKAR DIPANKAR","published":"May 2011","price":39.99,"publishedYM":"2011-05"}'>
            <td><img src="images/4965OS_Nginx%201%20Web%20Server%20Implementation%20Cookbook.jpg" alt="Nginx 1 Web Server Implementation Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>Nginx 1 Web Server Implementation Cookbook</td>

            <td>Dipankar Sarkar</td>
            <td>May 2011</td>
            <td>$39.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"1048OT_HTML5%20Multimedia%20Development%20Cookbookcov.jpg","title":"HTML5 MULTIMEDIA DEVELOPMENT COOKBOOKCOV.JPG","authors":"CRUSE DALE JORDAN LEE","published":"May 2011","price":39.99,"publishedYM":"2011-05"}'>
            <td><img src="images/1048OT_HTML5%20Multimedia%20Development%20Cookbookcov.jpg" alt="HTML5 Multimedia Development Cookbookcov.jpg">
            </td>
            <td>HTML5 Multimedia Development Cookbookcov.jpg</td>
            <td>Dale Cruse, Lee Jordan</td>
            <td>May 2011</td>
            <td>$39.99</td>

          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"0942OT_Core%20Data%20Essentials_0.jpg","title":"CORE DATA ESSENTIALS.JPG","authors":"HARWANI B.M.","published":"April 2011","price":44.99,"publishedYM":"2011-04"}'>
            <td><img src="images/0942OT_Core%20Data%20Essentials_0.jpg" alt="Core Data Essentials.jpg">
            </td>
            <td>Core Data Essentials.jpg</td>
            <td>B.M. Harwani</td>
            <td>April 2011</td>
            <td>$44.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"3524OS_WordPress%203%20Plugin%20Development%20Essentials_0.jpg","title":"WORDPRESS 3 PLUGIN DEVELOPMENT ESSENTIALS","authors":"BONDARI BRIAN GRIFFITHS EVERETT","published":"March 2011","price":39.99,"publishedYM":"2011-03"}'>
            <td><img src="images/3524OS_WordPress%203%20Plugin%20Development%20Essentials_0.jpg" alt="WordPress 3 Plugin Development Essentials">
            </td>
            <td>WordPress 3 Plugin Development Essentials</td>

            <td>Brian Bondari, Everett Griffiths</td>
            <td>March 2011</td>
            <td>$39.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"9867_Latex%20cov.jpg","title":"LATEX BEGINNER&rsquo;S GUIDE","authors":"KOTTWITZ STEFAN","published":"March 2011","price":44.99,"publishedYM":"2011-03"}'>
            <td><img src="images/9867_Latex%20cov.jpg" alt="LaTeX Beginner's Guide">
            </td>
            <td>LaTeX Beginner's Guide</td>
            <td>Stefan Kottwitz</td>
            <td>March 2011</td>
            <td>$44.99</td>

          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"2923OS_Panda3D%20game%20developer%E2%80%99s%20cookbook.jpg","title":"PANDA3D 1.7 GAME DEVELOPER&rsquo;S COOKBOOK","authors":"LANG CHRISTOPH","published":"March 2011","price":44.99,"publishedYM":"2011-03"}'>
            <td><img src="images/2923OS_Panda3D%20game%20developer%E2%80%99s%20cookbook.jpg" alt="Panda3D 1.7 Game Developer's Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>Panda3D 1.7 Game Developer's Cookbook</td>
            <td>Christoph Lang</td>
            <td>March 2011</td>
            <td>$44.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"1926_Cake%20PHP%201.3cov.jpg","title":"CAKEPHP 1.3 APPLICATION DEVELOPMENT COOKBOOK","authors":"IGLESIAS MARIANO","published":"March 2011","price":39.99,"publishedYM":"2011-03"}'>
            <td><img src="images/1926_Cake%20PHP%201.3cov.jpg" alt="CakePHP 1.3 Application Development Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>CakePHP 1.3 Application Development Cookbook</td>

            <td>Mariano Iglesias</td>
            <td>March 2011</td>
            <td>$39.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"4804os_mockupcover_ex.jpg","title":"MAGENTO 1.4 THEMES DESIGN","authors":"CARTER RICHARD","published":"January 2011","price":39.99,"publishedYM":"2011-01"}'>
            <td><img src="images/4804os_mockupcover_ex.jpg" alt="Magento 1.4 Themes Design">
            </td>
            <td>Magento 1.4 Themes Design</td>
            <td>Richard Carter</td>
            <td>January 2011</td>
            <td>$39.99</td>

          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"0349OS_MockupCover_0.jpg","title":"DJANGO JAVASCRIPT INTEGRATION: AJAX AND JQUERY","authors":"HAYWARD JONATHAN","published":"January 2011","price":44.99,"publishedYM":"2011-01"}'>
            <td><img src="images/0349OS_MockupCover_0.jpg" alt="Django JavaScript Integration: AJAX and jQuery">
            </td>
            <td>Django JavaScript Integration: AJAX and jQuery</td>
            <td>Jonathan Hayward</td>
            <td>January 2011</td>
            <td>$44.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-book='{"img":"1445OS_MockupCover_Magento_1.4_Development_Cookbook_cb.jpg","title":"MAGENTO 1.4 DEVELOPMENT COOKBOOK","authors":"FERDOUS NURUL","published":"December 2010","price":44.99,"publishedYM":"2010-12"}'>
            <td><img src="images/1445OS_MockupCover_Magento_1.4_Development_Cookbook_cb.jpg" alt="Magento 1.4 Development Cookbook">
            </td>
            <td>Magento 1.4 Development Cookbook</td>

            <td>Nurul Ferdous</td>
            <td>December 2010</td>
            <td>$44.99</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <table id="t-3" class="sortable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th data-sort='{"key":"title"}'>Title</th>
            <th data-sort='{"key":"authors"}'>Author(s)</th>
            <th data-sort='{"key":"publishedYM"}'>Publish Date</th>
            <th data-sort='{"key":"price"}'>Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        </tbody>

      </table>
    </div>
</body>
<script>

     
         /************************************************
  Set up table headings.
************************************************/
(($) => {
  $.cssHooks.glowColor = {
    set(elem, value) {
      elem.style.textShadow = value == 'none' ?
        '' : `0 0 2px ${value}`;
    }
  };
})(jQuery);

$(() => {
  $('table')
    .each((i, table) => {
      $('<h3/>', {
        'class': 'table-title',
        id: `table-title-${i}`,
        text: `Table ${i + 1}`,
        data: { index: i },
        click(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(table).fadeToggle();
        },
        css: { glowColor: '#00ff00', cursor: 'pointer' }
      }).insertBefore(table);
    });
});

const sortKeys = {
  date: ($cell) => Date.parse(`1 ${$cell.text()}`),
  alpha: ($cell) => $cell.text().toUpperCase(),
  numeric($cell) {
    const key = parseFloat($cell.text().replace(/^[^\d.]*/, ""));
    return isNaN(key) ? 0 : key;
  },
};

$(() => {
      const comparator = (a, b, direction = 1) =>
        a < b ? -direction : a > b ? direction : 0;

      const getTitleLength = ($cell) => $cell.text().trim().length;

      $("#t-1")
        .find("thead th")
        .wrapInner($("<a/>").attr("href", "#"))
        .addClass("sort")
        .on("click", (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();

          const $target = $(e.currentTarget);
          const column = $target.index();
          const sortDirection = $target.hasClass("sorted-asc") ? -1 : 1;

          const $tbody = $("#t-1").find("tbody");
          const $rows = $tbody.find("tr");

          $rows.sort((a, b) => {
            const valueA = getTitleLength($(a).find("td").eq(1));
            const valueB = getTitleLength($(b).find("td").eq(1));

            return comparator(valueA, valueB, sortDirection);
          });

          $rows.detach().appendTo($tbody);

          $target
            .siblings()
            .addBack()
            .removeClass("sorted-asc sorted-desc")
            .end()
            .end()
            .addClass(sortDirection == 1 ? "sorted-asc" : "sorted-desc");
        });
    });


/************************************************
  Table 2: Sorting by reading HTML5 data.
************************************************/
$(() => {
  const comparator = (a, b, direction = 1) =>
    a < b ?
      -direction :
      (a > b ? direction : 0);

  $('#t-2')
    .find('thead th')
    .slice(1)
    .wrapInner($('<a/>').attr('href', '#'))
    .addClass('sort')
    .on('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      const $target = $(e.currentTarget);
      const column = $target.index();
      const sortKey = $target.data('sort').key;
      const sortDirection = $target.hasClass('sorted-asc') ?
        -1 : 1;

      $('#t-2')
        .find('tbody > tr')
        .get()
        .sort((a, b) => comparator(
          $(a).data('book')[sortKey],
          $(b).data('book')[sortKey],
          sortDirection
        ))
        .forEach((element) => {
          $(element)
            .parent()
            .append(element);
        });

      $target
        .siblings()
        .addBack()
        .removeClass('sorted-asc sorted-desc')
        .end()
        .end()
        .addClass(
          sortDirection == 1 ?
            'sorted-asc' : 'sorted-desc'
        );
    });
});

/************************************************
  Table 3: Sorting by recreating HTML from JSON.
************************************************/
(($) => {
  const buildAuthors = (row, separator = ', ') =>
    row
      .authors
      .map(a => `${a.first_name} ${a.last_name}`)
      .join(separator);

  const buildRow = row =>
    `
      <tr>
        <td><img src="images/${row.img}"></td>
        <td>${row.titleFormatted}</td>
        <td>${row.authorsFormatted}</td>
        <td>${row.published}</td>
        <td>$${row.price}</td>
      </tr>
    `;

  const prepRows = rows =>
    rows
      .map(row => $.extend({}, row, {
        title: row.title.toUpperCase(),
        titleFormatted: row.title,
        authors: buildAuthors(row, ' ').toUpperCase(),
        authorsFormatted: buildAuthors(row)
      }));

  const buildRows = rows =>
    rows
      .map(buildRow)
      .join('');

  Promise.all([$.getJSON('books.json'), $.ready])
    .then(([json]) => {
      $('#t-3')
        .find('tbody')
        .html(buildRows(prepRows(json)));

      const comparator = (a, b, direction = 1) =>
        a < b ?
          -direction :
          (a > b ? direction : 0);

      $('#t-3')
        .find('thead th')
        .slice(1)
        .wrapInner($('<a/>').attr('href', '#'))
        .addClass('sort')
        .on('click', (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();

          const $target = $(e.currentTarget);
          const column = $target.index();
          const sortKey = $target.data('sort').key;
          const sortDirection = $target.hasClass('sorted-asc') ?
            -1 : 1;
          const content = buildRows(
            prepRows(json).sort((a, b) => comparator(
              a[sortKey],
              b[sortKey],
              sortDirection
            ))
          );

          $('#t-3')
            .find('tbody')
            .html(content);

          $target
            .siblings()
            .addBack()
            .removeClass('sorted-asc sorted-desc')
            .end()
            .end()
            .addClass(
              sortDirection == 1 ?
                'sorted-asc' : 'sorted-desc'
            );
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
})(jQuery);

          
          
      </script>
</html>
```

Here is the code for sorting Table 1 data by the number of characters in the title.

**Output:**

[image]